# C++ Неявно вызывается лишний конструктор. Классы как поля другого класса

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Есть простенькая программа на с++. Есть три класса, один содержит приватными полями 2 других. При вызове конструктора первого неявно вызываются конструкторы остальных. Вопрос почему? и что более важно, как этого избежать?

```
    class Device
        {
        private:
            Date date;
            TypeSensor type;
            int placeBinding;
            Sensor sensor;
......
    }
```

То есть при вызове конструктора девайс вызывается конструктор Date. Все бы ничего, но TypeSensor нужно инициализироват ранее, нежели остальные поля. Поэтому интересно есть ли способы решения этой проблемы.

```
enum TypeSensor {
    ACCELEROMETER,
    PROXYMETER,
    TEMPERATURE
};
class Sensor
{

    string unitOfMeasured;
    int maximum;
    int minimum;
    float value;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

В языке С++ конструктор объекта класса всегда вызывает конструкторы всех его подобъектов. Так работает язык С++. Избежать этого нельзя.

Порядок инициализации подобъектов определятся видом подобъекта (базовый подобъект или подобъект-член) и порядком объявления подобъекта среди аналогичных подобъектов. В вашем случае требуемого вам порядка инициализации можно достичь просто переупорядочиванием объявлений членов класса.

Однако если вам нужен какой-то специфический порядок инициализации подобъктов, то лучше достичь его не манипуляциями с порядком объявления, а другими средствами. А именно: лучше отложить инициализацию всех или некоторых подобъектов, а затем выполнить ее вручную в требуемом вам порядке. Этого можно достичь разными способами.

- Можно сделать конструктор по умолчанию подобъекта ничего не делающим, а для фактической инициализации предоставить специальный метод.
- Можно сделать агрегацию подобъектов не напрямую, а через умный указатель `std::unique_ptr`.
- Вместо агрегации объектов напрямую можно агрегировать `std::optional`.

И т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Порядок инициализации переменных определяется их следованием в объявлении класса. Переставьте в объявлении класса  `TypeSensor` и `Date`, что бы `TypeSensor` инициализировался первым.

```
class Device
    {
    private:
        TypeSensor type;
        Date date;
        int placeBinding;
        Sensor sensor;
}
```

Непонятно чего вы хотите избежать.  При создании объекта, обязаны инициализироваться все поля класса. Если в объявлении класса стоит `Date date;` то это поле обязано проинициализироваться при создании `Device`.

Однако если вы хотите избежать вызова конструктора `Date` то можно сделать указатель на него `Date* date;` и выделить память в другом месте.

Comment: Дело в том, что это перечисление(я хотел в Device конструкторе инициализировать его, то есть что бы пользователь сам ввел циферку и тогда уже определилось значение енюм), и насколько я знаю, там конструктора нету...

Comment: Покажите реализацию конструктора `Device`

Comment: `Device::Device()
{
 int n;
 cout << "choise 1, 2 or 3 type of sensor: " << endl;
 cout << "1. ACCELEROMETER" << endl;
 cout << "2. PROXYMETER" << endl;
 cout << "3. TEMPERATURE" << endl;
 cin >> n;
 switch (n)
 {
 case 1: this->type = TypeSensor::ACCELEROMETER; break;
 case 2: this->type = TypeSensor::PROXYMETER; break;
 case 3: this->type = TypeSensor::TEMPERATURE; break;
 default:
  break;
 }
  Sensor s;
  this->sensor = s;
}`

Comment: мне полностью подходит инициализация обектов, дело в том, что в enum(TypeSensor) нету конструктора, поэтому я не огу правильно его проинициализировать.

Comment: Так не надо. Сделайте отдельную функцию ввода, и в конструктор добавьте параметр `SensorType`

Comment: @Andriy и несмотря на то что у enum нет конструктора, вы можете проинициализировать поле класса в списке иницализаций в конструкторе, см. ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

Никак не связано с вопросом, но у Вас `SensorType` вынесен из класса `Sensor`. Может быть есть смысл сделать `SensorType` частью класса `Sensor` и передавать его в конструктор? 
Как-нибудь так, например:

```
class Sensor
{
public:
    enum class Type{
        DEFAULT = 0,
        ACCELEROMETER = 0,
        PROXYMETER = 1,
        TEMPERATURE = 2
    };

    explicit Sensor(const Type& type = Type::DEFAULT):
        m_unitOfMeasured{},
        m_maximum{1},
        m_minimum{0},
        m_value{0.0},
        m_type{type}
    {
        switch (m_type) {
        case Type::ACCELEROMETER:
            m_unitOfMeasured = "acceleration";
            ...
            break;
        case Type::PROXYMETER:
            m_unitOfMeasured = "level";
            ...
            break;
        case Type::TEMPERATURE:
            m_unitOfMeasured = "degree";
            ...
            break;
        default:
            ...
            break;
        }
    }

private:
    std::string m_unitOfMeasured;
    int m_maximum;
    int m_minimum;
    float m_value;
    Type m_type;
};

class Date{};

class Device
{
public:
    Device(const Sensor::Type& sensorType = Sensor::Type::DEFAULT):
        m_sensor{sensorType},
        m_date{},
        m_placeBinding{}
    {}
private:
    Sensor m_sensor;
    Date m_date;
    int m_placeBinding;


};
```

UPD. Ну тогда вот так как-то:

```
enum class SensorType{
    DEFAULT = 0,
    UNKNOW = 0,
    ACCELEROMETER = 1,
    PROXYMETER = 2,
    TEMPERATURE = 3
};


class Sensor
{
public:

    Sensor(const SensorType& type = SensorType::DEFAULT):
        m_unitOfMeasured{},
        m_maximum{1},
        m_minimum{0},
        m_value{0.0},
        m_type{type}
    {
        switch (m_type) {
        case SensorType::ACCELEROMETER:
            m_unitOfMeasured = "acceleration";
            break;
        case SensorType::PROXYMETER:
            m_unitOfMeasured = "level";
            break;
        case SensorType::TEMPERATURE:
            m_unitOfMeasured = "degree";
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

private:
    std::string m_unitOfMeasured;
    int m_maximum;
    int m_minimum;
    float m_value;
    SensorType m_type;
};

class Date{};

class Device
{
public:
    Device(const Date& date, const int placeBinding, const SensorType& sensorType= SensorType::DEFAULT):
        m_type{sensorType},
        m_sensor{sensorType},
        m_date{date},
        m_placeBinding{placeBinding}
    {}
    Device(const Device& other):
        m_type{other.m_type},
        m_sensor{other.m_sensor},
        m_date{other.m_date},
        m_placeBinding{other.m_placeBinding}
    {
    }
    static Device createByUser(){
        int n;
        std::cout << "choise 1, 2 or 3 type of sensor: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1. ACCELEROMETER" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. PROXYMETER" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. TEMPERATURE" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> n;
        if (n >= 1 && n <= 3){
            return Device(Date(), 0, static_cast<SensorType>(n));
        }else{
            return Device(Date(), 0);
        }
    }
private:
    SensorType m_type;
    Sensor m_sensor;
    Date m_date;
    int m_placeBinding;
};
```

Comment: Согласен, архитектура скверная, но таковы условия лабораторной, Тип сенсора должен быть полем в девайсе, а не в самом сенсоре.